# Looping through certain model columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a post model with a bunch of boolean columns that I want to loop through instead of manually checking each of them. However, I don't want to loop through every column in the model - just a particular set.

I found a solution to loop through all columns of a model:

```
user.columns.each do |column|
```

But how could I specify only certain columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a method like `.find_all` to filter, for example by name:

```
User.columns.find_all { |column| ['name', 'created_at'].include? column.name }.each do |column|
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the method you found, on a sample class:

```
> Post.columns.last
=> #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLColumn:0x007feee6bc2320
 @array=false,
 @cast_type=
  #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQL::OID::Integer:0x007feee6bd36c0
   @limit=nil,
   @precision=nil,
   @range=-2147483648...2147483648,
   @scale=nil>,
 @default="1",
 @default_function=nil,
 @name="max_likes",
 @null=false,
 @sql_type="integer">
```

Let's say there are 12 posts.

```
> Post.count
=> 12
```

All of the values on `columns` are accessible, and can be used to limit the results.

```
> Post.columns.count { |c| c.name == 'max_likes' }
=> 1
> Post.columns.count { |c| c.sql_type == 'integer' }
=> 5
> Post.columns.count { |c| c.precision == nil }
=> 12
> Post.columns.count { |c| c.default == "1" }
=> 2
```

Once you've filtered, you can do whatever you need with the selected column:

```
> Post.columns.select { |c| c.name == 'max_likes' }.each do |c|
    puts c.sql_type
  end
=> integer
```